# Opening custom file from iCloud into Xamarin.iOS app doesn't work

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icloud

We have `Xamarin.iOS` application that declares a custom file extension - `*.msoisalesbak` as exported type declaration

```xml
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.ewsgroup.msoisalesbak</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pkware.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>msoisalesbak</string>
        </dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>MSO&amp;I Sales application backup file</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This means, that whenever iOS system detects a file with this extension, it will provide a possibility to open this file in our application.

Further, in our `AppDelegate` we have a code like this to handle the delegating file share:

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
    ..................
    var fileHandlerService = ServiceLocator.Container.Resolve<IAssociatedFileHandlerService>();
    if(fileHandlerService.CanRestoreDatabaseFromOpenedAssociatedBackupFile(url))
    {
        ...................
        string filePath = url.Path;
        var destinationPath = "PATH_TO_APP_INTERNAL_FOLDER"
        using(FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using(FileStream destinationStream = File.Create(destinationPath))
        {
            sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
        }
        ....................
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

We basically double check that the file is valid and something we can handle, and then try to copy the file to internal storage and do some additional processing, which is not related to this issue.

Now, we create the custom file that our application supports and put it into iCloud Downloads folder. When we click on that file, our application is successfully opened and `OpenUrl` delegate is successfully invoked. However, doing so we receive the following exception

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads/637569517947945130-0.12.1.msoisalesbak".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00177]
```

Which means, for some reason the path that the `OpenUrl` received, is inaccessible for our application.

The fact is that `OpenUrl` works just fine if we have the custom file in an email, or we open the custom file from other applications like a chat app (Microsoft Teams as an example). However, it doesn't work from iCloud.

Is there any special care we should take, to allow access to iCloud folder? What is the thing that we miss?

Comment: Did you call "startAccessingSecurityScopedResource"? And try to modify "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" in info.plist.

Comment: Just curious, how do you have await without async?

Comment: @IvanIčin copy paste.... that code is not actually in that method :) brought it for brevity. I'll make the method async though to get rid of the confusion! thanks for noticing

Comment: @KyleWang-MSFT indeed, adding url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() solved the problem. Thanks a lot. To pay you a credit, would you like to create an answer, instead of me answering my own question?

Comment: @KyleWang-MSFT another observation. Instead of using  url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() you can simply set the LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace to false, which will result in the fact that the file will be copied to a temporary location, and then my app would continue working like before. And I actually rely on the fact that it'd be a temporary file, as we delete the URL path after we process the file. So, in my case setting LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace  to false was enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you "unlock" the file from iCloud, you need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` to makes the resource pointed to by a security-scoped URL available to the app. And then don't forget to call the `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource`.

You can also create a new boolean key `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` in the Info.plist file. If set it to true, the url will point to the file in iCloud but it hasn't be downloaded. So you can't access the file. If set it to false, it will makes a copy of the file in the Application Sandbox.